# OpenCSV error using CsvToBeanBuilder(FileReader())

Tags: java, android, javabeans, filereader, opencsv

*I am using OpenCSV in an Android Java project with IntelliJ.*

I am trying to run the following code to create a bean inside my project. Note the segment surrounded by "** **"

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);


            **List<Restrictions> restrictionData = new CsvToBeanBuilder(FileReader("restrictions.csv"))
                    .withType(Restrictions.class).build.parse();**
    }
}
```

I have taken this code from OpenCSV's site where they say:

> Here we simply name the fields identically to the header names. After
> that, reading is a simple job:

> List beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(FileReader("yourfile.csv"))
> .withType(Visitors.class).build().parse();

> This will give you a list of the two beans as defined in the example input file. Note how type conversions to basic data types (wrapped and unwrapped primitives, enumerations, and Strings) occur automatically.

My code resembles their same style. Here is the error I get:

```
C:\Programming\Android\GoTimeJavaVersion\app\src\main\java\com\example\gotimejavaversion\MainActivity.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            List<Restrictions> restrictionData = new CsvToBeanBuilder(FileReader("restrictions.csv"))
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   method FileReader(String)
  location: class MainActivity
```

I have tried putting 'new' in front of FileReader, and when I do this I get THIS error:

```
C:\Programming\Android\GoTimeJavaVersion\app\src\main\java\com\example\gotimejavaversion\MainActivity.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                    .withType(Restrictions.class).build.parse();
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable build
  location: class CsvToBeanBuilder
```

I have OpenCSV and beanutils in my library, both implemented in my build.gradle, and my file restrictions.csv is in my app's src folder. My Restrictions class also has no errors and follows OpenCSV's bean setup to a tee.

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use any of the below constructors for CsvToBeanBuilder. Constructor you are using is not valid :-

```
CsvToBeanBuilder(CSVReader csvReader)
CsvToBeanBuilder(Reader reader)
```

example :-

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("restrictions.csv"));
List<Restrictions> restrictionData = new CsvToBeanBuilder(csvReader)
                .withType(Restrictions.class)
                .build()
                .parse();
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav. So, I don't quite understand. I don't know how to implement what you have just suggested with my current code i.e. what that looks like. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Gaurav! I am still having the following issue: build is in red text and when I run I get a similar error I was getting with build before: `C:\Programming\Android\GoTimeJavaVersion\app\src\main\java\com\example\gotimejavaversion\MainActivity.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                .withType(Restrictions.class).build.parse();
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable build
  location: class CsvToBeanBuilder`

Comment: Fixed the error ^, please try the code again